# Is !NaN not a NaN?

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, nan

I came across this code that spews a warning with `gcc`:

```
float f;
// Calculate a value for f
if (!f == 0.0)
{
    // Handle it being non-zero
}
```

It was probably just a typo by another team member, and examining the code what was really meant was:

```
if (f != 0.0)
// OR
if (!(f == 0.0))
```

I've corrected the code, but I was just wondering what would `!NaN` evaluate to. We use the `f` value inside the `if`, so we don't want `NaN`s getting past the check.

Comment: Remember that due to imprecision in floating point computations `f != 0.0`may not be sufficient. You will likely [need an epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) in there.

Comment: Is `f` being initialized before the condition? What makes you think the value of `f` is NaN? And what warnings do you get?

Comment: `f` should never be a `NaN` (barring cosmic rays twiddling a bit or two!) - this is for my own intellectual curiosity rather than an actual live bug, hence the [tag:language-lawyer] tag.

Comment: @user4581301 It's actually a constant that gets initialised from (basically) an environment variable, so someone setting it to "0.000000000000000000001" is not my problem! 0.0 means not initialised from the environment.

Comment: Good enough. That was just a general warning because the only given information about what we can expect in `f` at the time of the test, `// Calculate a value for f`, suggests some math is involved. NaN is an odd beast with many shapes. Looking forward to seeing what, if anything, the language lawyers come up with in response to what `!NaN` even means.

Comment: `!f` is a `bool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

> A prvalue of integral, floating-point, unscoped enumeration, pointer, and pointer-to-member types can be converted to a prvalue of type bool.
>
> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become false. All other values become true

Therefore `!f == 0.0` is equivalent to `!(f != 0.0) == 0.0` or `(f == 0.0) == false` or `f != 0.0`

Comment: Excellent! But to answer completely the question, you still have to say what the f!=0.0 will be for a NaN (hint:  the last para of your quote answers the question without rewriting any term :-) )

Comment: I was also worried about [floating-point exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) as `gcc` has them on by default, I think. Would `!NaN` raise a floating-point exception? I also found this [a useful reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/signaling_NaN).

Comment: @Christophe do you really think its necessary to explicitly state that a non-zero value compared to zero returns false?

Comment: @KenY-N I think the behaviour is the same with either expression, if `NaN != 0` throws an exception then `!NaN` will too.

Comment: @KenY-N GCC on Linux/x86-64 by default does not raise an exception for arithmetic operations producing or involving a NaN, not even a signalling NaN. I don't know about Windows. (The only NaNs that are not quiet, by the way, are the ones explicitly made e.g. by calling `std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN()`.) If, for any reason, you do want exceptions for signalling NaNs, call `feenableexcept(FE_INVALID)` [as explained here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/g77/Floating_002dpoint-Exception-Handling.html).

Comment: @PeteBecker according to the [font of all knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN) `NaN != 0.0` returns true not false.

Comment: @AlanBirtles -- you're right, and not just according to Wikipedia. That's what IEEE-754 says. `!=` is true for unordered. Sorry about that. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid a NaN inside `if`, you can use the function

`bool isnan( float arg );`

to perform a check.

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) of the function:

> **NaN values never compare equal to themselves or to other NaN values.** Copying a NaN is not required, by IEEE-754, to preserve its bit representation (sign and payload), though most implementation do.

Another way to test if a floating-point value is NaN is to compare it with itself:

```
bool is_nan(double x) { return x != x; }
```

The C++ draft (N4713) states:

> **8.5.2.1 Unary operators [expr.unary.op]**
>   ...
>   9. The operand of the logical negation operator `!` **is contextually converted to bool** (Clause 7); its value is `true` if the converted operand is `false` and `false` otherwise. **The type of the result is bool**.
>
> **7.14 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]**
>   1. A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
>   **any other value is converted to true.**

**Conclusion:** As NaN is contextually converted as `true` in the expression `!NaN`, `!NaN` is `false` and thus **not a NaN**.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
if (!isnan(f)&& !f == 0.0)
    {
        cout<<"Filtered NaN values"<<endl;

    }
```